# How can I use DriveDroid to install Ubuntu on a dead PC?

Tags: system-installation, bootloader, grubrescue

My laptop is stuck in GRUB rescue mode. I tried:

```
set boot=(hd0,msdos1)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
```

and anything else I found on the internet, but everything lead to `unknown system file` or `no such partition`.

So I decided to root my phone and install [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid), but I can't startup the laptop to connect my phone, so I have  no way to do it.

When I turn on my laptop and press <kbd>F2</kbd>, it will open inside the setup utility, but I can't find anything there to help me fix the rescue mode.

Comment: Can you boot an OS from live USB in your laptop?

Comment: Dead PC, or dead storage device?

Comment: Can you precisely describe what you did?